# Firebase Authentication on Android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm curious about the security of the Firebase login process for Android.

Assume that I'm logging in with Google, according to [this tutorial](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/google-signin)

From what I can see, then authentication process is all done client-side. We get a `AuthCredential` object called `credential`, which we use to then sign in. So my question is: what prevents someone from bypassing the Google sign-in process altogether, create their own `AuthCredential` object and use that to log in? Is it that y app is signed, and so any attempt to modify it would void that signature?

I'm sure that this is secure, but I'm curious about the reasons why.

Thank you!

Comment: You would need the Firebase Access Token and Google Play API key, would you not?

Comment: Your question seems to boil down to "can someone bypass OAuth 2 authentication"

Comment: Ha. I know that OAuth2 works. But usually, Google would redirect to a url on my server with a token, and I don't see that happening here.

Comment: Your understanding of indirection is correct. When using FIrebase Google Oauth essentially redirects to a URL on the Firebase servers. There the OAuth token is validated and then a Firebase JWT is minted for it. So Firebase Authentication is definitely not serverless, but you don't have to be the one running code on a server.

Comment: Ah, so Firebase does do something on the server. A very kind thank you @FrankvanPuffelen, this is exactly the information I was looking for :)